# Removing whitespace while copying column in one line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am copying a column with `awk` and copying to a new file and trying to remove the white space in the file after it is copied, in one line, not managing to do so, here is what I have so far:

```
awk '{print $2}' input_file.txt > test.txt | sed -r 's/\s+//g' test.txt
```

after it is copied should look like this

```
//emptyline
//emptyline
1
2
3
4
```

after removing white space

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: You never need sed when you're already using awk. Your sed command is not deleting blank lines, it's removing sequences of contiguous blank chars on every line (IF your sed support `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`). Which do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let awk do all the work:

```
awk '$2{ print $2 }'
```

Awk splits on whitespace by default. If the second field evaluates to "true", then the above expression will print that second field.

If that second field could be "0" or another string that evaluates to "false", or if your field separator is not whitespace, you will need to be a little more explicit.

```
'$2 ~ /[^[:space:]]/{ print $2 }'
```

(The regex `[^[:space:]]` matches a string that contains at least one non-whitespace character.)

Comment: the command could fail, if the value of the second column is zero `0`

Comment: Not just if it **is** zero, but if its any string that could evaluate to zero. You need to test `$2!=""`. Also, the `.*`s are redundant in `/.*[^[:space:]].*/`, you could just write `/[^[:space:]]/` since that alone `matches a string that contains at least one non-whitespace character` and if you have `$2 ~ /[^[:space:]]/` then you don't need to `&&` it with `$2` unless you're specifically trying to exclude a value ot zero instead of empty. I'm really not sure what that 2nd script is intended to do anyway though.